# Unable to clear localStorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and am currently working on a simple counter, the idea is that you will be able to store your counts in localStorage and clear them when you like.

I have been building on the W3C example but have been unable to clear the localStorage.

I have tried setting the value to zero as well as simply clearing and removing the item, but here is where i am at so far:

```
function clickCounter()
{
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  if (localStorage.clickcount)
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    }
  else
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=1;
    }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  }
}

function cleanUp(){
    localStorage.clickcount=0;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br/>   

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<button onclick="cleanUp()">Reset button</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: because im an idiot, I added the missing parentheses but it's still not working

Comment: As far as I see it **is** working. http://jsfiddle.net/alvinhochun/y4bXE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy pasted your code into an empty HTML file and ran it, works fine

All I did was add the missing < script >

I'm using Chrome 22

FYI this is how you remove something from local storage

```
localStorage.removeItem('thekey');
```

Comment: I re copy/pasted it into my editor and it works perfectly all of a sudden, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your are using js. you can use this, if you want to clear all data from localStorage. `localStorage.clear();`

But if you only want to clear a single localStorage, use `localStorage.removeItem('key');`

Ex.

```
function cleanUp(){
    localStorage.clear(); //This clears all localStorage, when you click the button with this function

}
```